# Accessing a javascript function within a function from HTML

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code which launches a function on a button click

```
"<input type='text' id='myTest' value='user input' /><input type='button' value='submit' onclick='myFunction();' />"
```

This works when myFunction() is in the top level of my javascript, but it needs to be inside another function.  Is this possible???

Comment: Inline html event attributes can only access JS's global scope. So you can access your nested function if you add a global-level reference to it, or if you bind your event handler from within your JS (rather than inline) at a point that has access to the function.

Comment: I guess that depends on what exactly you mean by "it needs to be inside another function". A complete example helps.

Comment: I think @alex436's answer has the working example, but I'm really curious about the use-case & why it requires the form's submit handler to be a function within a function.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats what you want?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var myEventListener = new myFunc1();
    document.getElementById(mybutton).onclick(myEventListener.myFunc2);

    function myFunc1(){
       this.myFunc2 = function(){
          //DO STUFF...
       }
       //DO OTHER STUFF
    }
}
```

html:

```
 <input id="mybutton" type='button' value='submit'/>
```

Comment: `myFunc1.myFunc2` and `this.myFunc2` is quite wrong.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: The function `myFunc1` does not have a property `myFunc2`. The code inside `myFunc1` is never executed since you are not calling `myFunc1`, hence `myFunc2` is never created. However, even if you called `myFunc1`, `this` does **not** refer to the function object itself. So it still wouldn't create `myFunc1.myFunc2`. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this to learn more about `this`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of scope. The `onclick` scope in your DOM cannot see your function-within-a-function & therefore cannot call it. If you want to use `onclick`, you will need to define your function in the global scope (or better yet, use jQuery with [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) or [`.on('click', ...)`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a nice solution, but it works with the drawback of the need to initialize the function for registering the inner function.

```
function fn() {
    function pi() {
        document.getElementById('myTest').value = Math.PI;
    }
    if (fn.pi) {
        // this is the part for the usual function body
        // skips at the first call
        return 777;
    }
    // make pi public
    fn.pi = pi;
}
fn(); // init function
```

Add at some suitable place:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='myTest' value='user input' />
    <input type='button' value='submit' onclick='fn.pi();' />
</form>
```